import NextAuth statement not working properly
Using next auth, documentation says import NextAuth from 'next-auth', but in vs code suggestions says import nextAuth from next-auth.
(letters case difference).
When I install beta version everything works fine. Anyone here to help?
I updated typescript version, did npm i next-auth@latest but nothing worked.

I don't think that's a big deal since you're using default import name does not matter, wether it's nextAuth or NextAuth it will import the default export.
